# Foreach with session data

Tags: php, session, foreach

I don't have much knowledge, but I'm turning around, but I came across the following question, which seems to be simple in my view, but I found no answers or examples. If you can help me, please.

I get a list of 5 items on the paeg access.php

```
    <?php
session_start ();
foreach($followers as $value){

    $_SESSION['username_recente'] = $value['username'];
    $_SESSION['full_name_recente'] = $value['full_name'];
    $_SESSION['profile_pic_url_recente'] = $value['profile_pic_url'];
    $_SESSION['followed_by_viewer_recente'] = $value['followed_by_viewer'];
}
```

Return this to me:

```
Username: johndoe1
Fullname: john doe 1
profile_pic: http://....
followed: true

Username: johndoe2
Fullname: john doe 2
profile_pic: http://....
followed: true

I have 5 results of these.
```

With a simple echo, on that same page, I get the 5 items I want.

However, on the next page, index.php, there is only the first item on the list.

index.php

```
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
print $key . '<br>';
print $value;
}
```

returns me only 1 result in index.php

```
Username: johndoe1
Fullname: john doe 1
profile_pic: http://....
followed: true
```

Am I using the functions correctly? I do not think so.
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "5 items"? I only see 4 assignments. And is the session started (using `session_start()`) in `index.php`?

Comment: Can you please give us an example of the expected output and what you're currently getting? The question is a bit ambiguous at the moment. A stab in the dark would be that you're overwriting the same session variables on each iteration in the first foreach. In the end, it will only contain the values from the last follower.

Comment: Foreach returns 5 items to me in the query in access.php. Example: Username1, Username2, Username3, Username4, Username5. In addition to the other attributes, such as "full_name" ...

I want to take these 5 results (which bring these 4 assignments) to index.php. However, only 1 result comes (with 4 assignments)

Yes, index.php has session_stat ();

Comment: I edited the question with the results. I tried to explain it in the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You're only creating a single dimension with those keys, so for example `$_SESSION['username_recente']` is overwritten each time through the loop and there will only be one.  You'll need a multi-dimensional array of some sort.  Here's an example similar to how database rows are returned:

```
foreach($followers as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key]['username_recente'] = $value['username'];
    $_SESSION[$key]['full_name_recente'] = $value['full_name'];
    $_SESSION[$key]['profile_pic_url_recente'] = $value['profile_pic_url'];
    $_SESSION[$key]['followed_by_viewer_recente'] = $value['followed_by_viewer'];
}
```

Then:

```
//required    
session_start();

foreach ($_SESSION as $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        print "$key : $value<br>";
    }
}
```

If you can use the same keys from `$followers` in `$_SESSION` then for the first page, just:

```
$_SESSION = $followers;
//or better
$_SESSION['followers'] = $followers;
```

Then on the next page loop `$_SESSION['followers']`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still get only 1 result. Output: 
0
username1

Comment: Depends on what `$followers` looks like https://3v4l.org/0hSah  You did this `$_SESSION[$key] = ` right?

Comment: with a var_dump($_SESSION); i can see that the data is not in the session

Comment: You have `session_start();` on the second page?

Comment: Yes. With the old code, it displays only 1. With this new one none is displayed. var_dump displays stored data from my system, such as the user's login data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help comments, they were very helpful, but I managed to solve the problem as follows:

Save session data with:

```
$_SESSION['array'] = $followers;
```

the next page, just:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['array'] as $value) {
// values...
}
```

tks a lot